# I am trying to turn an array into string, php is confounding me though?

Tags: php, arrays, string

Hi I am trying to write a piece of code that will allow me to read from an array and then output the required text as string

The code in question:

```
$mytext = (string)$output[0];

$breakup = explode('--', $mytext);

echo "###########################################";
echo $breakup;
```

This is the first time I've tried doing this and I don't think implode would work.

Could someone shed some light on what I am doing wrong or help me reach an answer?

Comment: What does `$output[0]` contain? `explode()` returns an **array of strings**, each of which is a substring of string formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter. If you need to display all the values together, `implode()` is your friend. If not, you need to specify the array value to be outputted, like so: `echo $breakup[0];` etc.

Comment: Try a `print_r` on `$breakup`.

Comment: What is wrong with implode?

Comment: Are you trying to output each array item as a seperate line?  Currently $mytext is already a string, but by using explode() it becomes an array of strings (i.e. multiple strings).

Comment: Yes I am trying to break it into an array of strings. (also crikey you guys are quick, thanks!). Nothing is probably wrong with implode, I just couldn't get it working :/ I'm pretty new to php still.

Comment: Amal, would I use implode in much the same way though? I think I need to display each separately though. I'm trying to read from an error log, getting it to tell me when the system doesn't respond. So using this to separate the array into separate strings...

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
$myString = "bob-fred-john-sarah-claire-julie-lisa";

$ex = explode("-", $myString);
```

then to see whats in the $ex array you can print it out like this:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($ex);
echo "</pre>";
```

to access individual values of the array you use the array index like this (remember arrays start at index 0):

```
echo $ex[0];  //this will echo bob.    
echo $ex[1];  //this will echo fred.
```

to echo out each part of the $ex array you use something like a foreach loop:

```
foreach($ex as $index => $value){
    echo $value."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add `true` as second parameter to the `print_r`? This way the output is returned instead of printed ;)

Comment: @Benz  yes true can be passed too if you have the need to store the output of print_r in a variable  =)

Answer (score 0):

To print out the contents of the array individually you can do it this way:

```
$mytext = (string)$output[0];

$breakup = explode('--', $mytext);

echo "###########################################";

for ($i=0; $i<count($breakup); $i++) {
    echo $breakup[$i];
}
```

An alternative way is with foreach:

```
foreach ($breakup as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

As mentioned by others, print_r can be used for displaying an array in easily readable format:

```
print_r($breakup);
```

You can also use it to store a string:

```
$myvalue = print_r($breakup, true);  //note the ,true which will return the value instead of printing it.
```